# Passing List from controller to view with JSTL or EL

Tags: list, jsp, jstl, el, scriptlet

I would like to switch from scriplets to EL or JSTL, yet i simply cannot figure out how you hve to pass your attributes from the controllers to the view.

Lets say we have a list of cars in our controller, and we want to display them on our view.
With scriplets we would do:

```
<% List<Car> cars= (List) request.getAttribute("Cars"); %>
```

To retrieve the list from our controller to our view.

How is this done with EL or JSTL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are setting your list as follows from your controller -

```
request.setAttribute("items", items);
```

If this is the case, then you can access each item of this list as follows -

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}">
.......
</c:forEach>
```

If the list contains objects which have a property called, say, `price` (which means you have `getPrice` getter in the class), then you can do this to access that value -

```
${item.price}
```

inside that jstl loop.